# PHP way to calculate no of leaves in a fiscal year

Tags: php

Let's assume i have three dates in variables, like

Sample 1.

```
$datehire = "2013-01-06";
$dateaniv = "2014-01-06";
$companyFiscalYr = "2014-06-01";
```

I need to get the count of months after $dateAniv.
I should get 6 leaves if I count from $dateAniv til $companyFiscalYr

Sample 2.

```
$datehire = "2012-11-01";
$dateaniv = "2013-11-01";
$companyFiscalYr = "2014-06-01";

I should get 8 leaves
```

Thanks much

Comment: Does any part of a month count as a full month? If you go from 31-JAN to 1-MAR is that 2 or 3 months?

Comment: I'm a bit confused at the number of what the number of leaves mean. There is 1 year, 4 months, and 26 days between `2014-01-06` and `2015-06-01` (In sample 1). Tell me where I should get 6 leaves from.

Comment: Petter Bowers.. supposed to be its 3

Comment: Danhopes sorry mistype it. should be $companyFiscalYr = "2014-06-01";

Answer (score 0):

I don't yet have an answer to how you are defining "a month" from my comment above, but this will give you a start:

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%m months');
?>
```

Do note that this is probably going have difficulty if you go over 12 months.

If you defined a month as a 30-day period then you could use something like `$interval->format('$R%a')/30` and then `floor()` it or `round()` it.

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php and http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

---

Nope, upon reflection that's not going to work - dates the end of January will always mess you up because of the short month of Feb.  Try this instead:

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$months1 = $datetime1->format('%y')*12 + $datetime1->format('%m');
$months2 = $datetime2->format('%y')*12 + $datetime2->format('%m');
echo ($months2-$months1).' months');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks

I think this may do

```
    $date1 = new DateTime("2013-08-06");
    $date2 = new DateTime("2014-08-06");                            
    $FiscalYear = new DateTime("2015-06-06");
    $intervalFY = date_diff($date2, $FiscalYear);

    echo $intervalFY ->m + ($intervalFY ->y * 12) + 1 . ' months';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$datehire = "2013-01-06";
$dateaniv = "2014-01-06";
$companyFiscalYr = "2014-06-01";

$datetime1 = date_create($dateaniv);
$datetime2 = date_create($companyFiscalYr);
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
$leave = $interval->format('%m');
echo "Leaves:".$leave;
?>
```